# User-resizable WPF Controls?

Tags: wpf, xaml

In XAML, how do I make it possible to resize controls or portions of a display the way the different panels like the Toolbox, Solution Explorer or Error List in Visual Studio can be grabbed and resized?

In this made-up example . . .

```
<Window x:Class="UI_Experiments_1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <DockPanel x:Name="Tab3DockPanel" Background="#FFA0FFA0" LastChildFill="True">
        <ScrollViewer DockPanel.Dock="Left" Background="Lavender">
            <TextBlock Height="60" TextWrapping="Wrap" Background="#FFFFDDDD" Width="140">
                  ScrollViewer - DockPanel.Dock="Left"
            </TextBlock>
        </ScrollViewer> 
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
               TextWrapping="Wrap" Background="LemonChiffon">
               DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        </TextBlock>
        <ListBox DockPanel.Dock="Right" Background="#FFCCEEFF">
               ListBox DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" 
        </ListBox>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

. . . I have a DockPanel with a ScrollView docked on the left, a ListBox docked on the bottom, and a TextBlock on the top.    Is there a way to attach resizing handles to these to achieve the same effect, or is there some other control that these can be embedded in?   As I said, the above is just a made-up example to experiment with - I don't care if I use those exact controls.

I did find an example of adding resizing handles using an Adorner on MSDN but it involved over 170 lines of C# code so before adopting that I wanted to be sure there was no intrinsic way to achieve this in XAML.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You might go with [GridSplitter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridsplitter.aspx)  What you will need to do is to do your layout with Grid and then use GridSplitter to resize columns or rows.

Here is an example on [How to: Create User-Resizable Applications with GridSplitter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/silverlight/dotnet-windows-silverlight/ff382751(v=vs.95))

Answer (score 21):

Not the exact controls you asked but a sample.  Need a splitter and what is on either side * and the contained control stretch.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />     
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
             VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
             Text="TexBox" />      
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2,0,2,0"
                  Width="3" Background="Purple" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <ListView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Background="Aqua" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Why would you set the width of the second `ColumnDefinition` to auto? This causes the `GridSplitter` to become resizable itself.

Comment: @DdW Really?   Did you test this?

Comment: yep... in combination with the `*` on the other two, it keeps the other two the same size, while resizing the `GridSplitter`. My advice: keep the width fixed (3 or 5 pixels or so) on both the `GridSplitter` and its `ColumnDefinition`

Comment: @DdW Don't know what to say?  Works fine for.

Comment: Minimal required attribute for `GridSplitter` seems to be `Grid.Column`, `HorizontalAlignment`, and `Width`. In addition, row definition is not essential if there is only one row.